# Rust - Typescript - Keyof

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and just wondering if there's an equivalent of the `keyof` (like in TypeScript) operator in Rust.

I don't know if this is possible, but I'm trying to access the key and value of a struct within another struct.

example:

```js
interface Events {
   msg:(data:string)=>any,
   abort:()=>any
}

class EventEmitter<T>{
   on(event: keyof T,callback:T[keyof T])
}
```

I'm trying to achieve the same `on` function in rust.

```rs
struct Events {
    msg: Fn(&str)->(),
    abort: Fn()->(),
}

struct EventEmitter<T> {
    pub listeners: Vec<Listener<T>>,
}
```

Context: I'm trying to recreate `EventEimtter` exactly like node.js & ts

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You can't access struct members via their string name like in dynamic languages.

Comment: @PitaJ I'm trying to recreate EventEmitter like in node.js for learning purposes and thus creating the same functionality.

Comment: That's not at all helpful, given you can't assume people using Rust have any clue about what you're trying to reproduce, but you never explain what it is, or what you're actually trying to achieve. However a rule, trying to 1:1 reproduce the functionality of a language in an other tends to be a bad idea, especially when the two languages in question are a respectively dynamically and weakly typed; and statically typed with barely any reflection. A classic essay on the subject is [Python is not Java](https://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html).

Comment: @Masklinn 
Thank you for taking the time to clarify. As I mentioned, I am new to Rust and may ask questions that seem stupid or unclear. 
I may also try to apply the logic of another language without realizing it. Sorry about that

Comment: No, nothing like the `keyof` operator exists in rust. You can probably achieve something similar by writing a trait, but you definitely cannot strongly type against a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming). As mentioned in the comments to your question, Rust does not have reflection as a native feature. Using a String to access members of your struct could potentially create unpredictable or undefined behavior.

If it truly is important to access members of your struct that have the same type, you could look into creating a trait called "Keyable" or something similar. This struct should (probably) look something like this.

```rust
pub trait Keyable<T> {
    fn get_string(&self, for_key: T) -> Option<&String>;
    fn get_i32(&self, key: T) -> Option<&i32>;
}
pub enum UserKeys {
    Id,
    Username,
    Password
}
pub struct User {
    id: i32,
    username: String,
    password: String
}
impl Keyable<UserKeys> for User {
    fn get_string(&self, key: UserKeys) -> Option<&String> {
        match key {
            UserKeys::Username => Some(&self.username),
            UserKeys::Password => Some(&self.password),
            _ => None
        }
    }
    fn get_i32(&self, key: UserKeys) -> Option<&i32> {
        match key {
            UserKeys::Id => Some(&self.id),
            _ => None
        }
    }
}
```

This would create a valid implementation of reflection in Rust. It is worth noting that you would not necessarily have to type all of this by hand; you could look into creating a Derive macro [(Rust Book)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#derive-macros).

You could then add a type bound to your EventEmitter so it becomes:

```rust
struct EventEmitter<K, T: Keyable<K>> {
    pub listeners: Vec<Listener<T>>,
}
```

This code says "I want to create a struct that can hold many instances of a Listener for type Keyable (T) with a certain key type (K).

There would still be quite a bit of work to do in order to get your events all connected, but taking care of reflection is a big step.

This is an example I've written that allows a derivation of a struct called ToJson. It allows all implementors to automatically inherit a to_json function that creates a String of all its properties. [GitHub](https://github.com/jacksonzamorano/airline-macros/blob/master/src/lib.rs)